# Add custom fields to the Stripe Google Pay/Apple Pay Payment Request Button payment popup

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Is it possible to customize the Stripe payment sheet to add a custom field in there (screenshot below)?

[image: Stripe Google pay payment sheet]

I have gone through the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button?client=html#html-js-collecting-shipping-info) but couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: This dialog is not specific to Stripe payment flows, but is the native Chrome UI for Google Pay. What specific details do you want to add to the dialog?

Comment: @JonathanSteele I would like to add a custom field - a date field and a dropdown. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: As far as I know, not with the Stripe implementation of the Payment Request API (which is what that UI is).

Comment: Great, that's what I thought. Thanks for your time @JonathanSteele